# How can I get the actual displayed text from an HTML TextNode instead of the HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xmlnode

I'm trying to turn a DOM node and all its children into a plain text markup of my design. I can use `node.childNodes` to get a list of all the content and recursively turn it into my string format.

However, when I take text out of a `TextNode`, it includes newlines and spaces that aren't visible on the page. For plain text I want to get the same appearance that was on the HTML - so there shouldn't be lots of indentations before the text or newlines after it, even if they were in the HTML markup, because my browser stripped those out when it rendered the HTML.

The obvious answer would be to `.trim()` the string myself - except that this can take out spaces that are supposed to exist in the text, in the case of something like `<em>text.</em> moretext`. The latter textnode loses the space before it.

Even if that was working it's also philosophically unappealing. I want this algorithm to be based on the text presented to the user. The webpage conceals implementation details like spaces, tabs, and newlines in the underlying markup and I would like to remain within that abstraction using whatever it used to trim them down, rather than the approximation granted by `trim()`. Ideally there would be an equivalent of `node.textContent` that has a list of both plain textand child elements somehow.

I haven't been able to find anything about this and I can't see a good way to code it to be smart about those spaces (short of comparing the `.textContent` and `.nodeValue` strings or parsing `innerHTML` myself or something). Help?

Comment: you can't reg replace "any number of whitespace chars together" with "a space"?

Comment: @PraveenKumar—what difference will jQuery make? It uses either textContent or node traversing (or innerText in less than recent versions).

Comment: @popnoodles: depends, is that what my browser does? Pretty sure it isn't. For example, two spaces at the start of a line get turned into none when displayed. I guess I could trim the whole string, do that to the middle, and restore spaces on the edges manually afterwards... but I still won't be sure if I'm exactly duplicating what the user is seeing on their screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("someid").innerText.replace(/\s+/g," ")
```

The **trim** method removes the space at the head and the end of a string, but not in the middle

Comment: That won't do it. The text isn't necessarily inside an element. It's generally going to be in a TextNode which is not necessarily the only child of its parent, and the spaces on the edges of the `node.nodeValue`  may or may not be visible on the webpage depending on if they come before some other node.


Additionally, that will replace newlines and tabs from the markup with spaces whereas I need them to not exist if they're not visible on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have written an implementation of exactly this as part of my [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy) library's [TextRange module](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule), but it's a lot of code to include for just this.

```
var displayedText = rangy.innerText(node);
```